# Looking at the Microsoft Office Interop Word Documentation, how was I supposed to figure out -1 = true?

Tags: c#, ms-word

Specifically, I was looking at the [Rows.HeadingFormat Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.rows.headingformat?view=word-pia)

> **Property Value**
>
> Int32
>
> **Remarks**
>
> This property returns true if the specified row or rows are formatted as a table heading, and false if not.
>
> Rows formatted as table headings are repeated when a table spans more than one page.
>
> This values this property can be set to are **True**, **False** and **wdUndefined**.

I had incorrectly assumed that 1 was true and 0 was false until I found the answer in a different thread. Why is -1 evaluated as true? and How are you supposed to know that/figure it out?

I googled around to see if that was a common convention, but I wasn't turning up any useful results.

Thanks!

Comment: It was a common convention in old-fashioned 1990s Visual Basic.  And, Excel automation derives from 1990s VB.  The reason is the a value of -1 has *all* bits in the value set to 1 (well, that's what I always assumed).

Comment: Yes, it's because boolean not was done as a bitwise not, and FWIW, that boolean (VT_BOOL) is 16 bits.

Comment: In general, it is best to assume that <>0 is true and 0 is false, but not to assume any particular value for true (the Perl/C model).

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310779/vba-why-would-the-not-operator-stop-working/59311115#59311115